# Apply Function to Datetime field in Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, datetime

I would like to create a field in my table by using a function comparing a datetime field with a certain date named as `data['RegisterDate']`

I wrote a function like that:

```
def OldNew(DateTime):
    if DateTime> '2019-09-04 00:00:00':
        return 'New'
    else:
        return 'Old'

OldNew('2019-09-05 00:00:00')
```

and it gives the correct result.

The format of the `data['RegisterDate']`  is the same with the format of `'2019-09-04 00:00:00'`

However, when i tried `data['NewColumn] = data['RegisterDate'].apply(OldNew)`

It gives the following error message.

`Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'`

I tried to convert the datetime column to string but failed.

Then I tried to implement some kind of decoding staff again I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: `if DateTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M-%S') > '2019-09-04 00:00:00':`

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_datetime`

**Ex:**

```
def OldNew(DateTime):
    if DateTime > pd.to_datetime('2019-09-04 00:00:00'):
        return 'New'
    else:
        return 'Old'
```

---

You can also use `np.where` instead of `.apply` for efficiency

**Ex:**

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'RegisterDate': ['2019-09-03 00:00:00', '2019-09-05 00:00:00']})
data["RegisterDate"] = pd.to_datetime(data["RegisterDate"])
data['NewColumn'] = np.where(data["RegisterDate"] > pd.to_datetime('2019-09-04 00:00:00'), 'New', 'Old')
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
  RegisterDate NewColumn
0   2019-09-03       Old
1   2019-09-05       New
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `str(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` and then compare.